# Core graphics or opengl for paint app?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, core-graphics

I've just started to sketch the features of an app containing a paint module. Such module will work like most painting apps, like Brushes or Colors; you'll have a brush, a pencil and a rubber, plus a numbers of colors.
I am wondering whether I should use OpenGL or CoreGraphics for the drawing routines. I am quite inexperienced in the iPhone drawing API, so I am open to all sort of suggestions.

Thanks in advance,
Davide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Graphics.  It's easier to use but still can do pretty much anything you need.

Comment: Yeah for simple application like drawing Core Graphics is enough.

Comment: is Drawsomething app developed by core graphics or openGL ?

Comment: @Pratheepch no idea; ask the OMGPOP folks.

Comment: @DaveDeLong hehe right.. !! okay can please tell me this , " Can a paint app with all features be created by openGL ? or anything else is better??

Answer (score 2):

I also started with core graphics but i ended on openGL:) There will be a point where you will need more. In my opinion you should jump to openGL. But as Dave said Core Graphics is much easier.